# Go module package not found when executing the tests

Tags: go, testing, module, package

I know I am lacking a fundamental understanding how Go is seeking for a package, but let me just emphasize my thoughts and if needed - you could downvote.

This is my structure of the Go module:

├── go.mod

├── gopher.json

├── main.go

├── story.go

├── template.html

└── tests

```
   ├── cyow_test.go
   └── gopher.json
```

Nothing too outside of the straightforward, dedicated /tests directory where the tests are supposed to be placed.

This is my cyow_test.go file:

```
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "story"
    "testing"
)

func TestUnmarshallOverStoryStruct(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    content, fileError := ioutil.ReadFile("gopher.json")
    if fileError != nil {
        t.Error("The file for Chapter is not found.")
    }

    story := story.Story{}
    fmt.Println("Story has been initialized")

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(content), &story)
    fmt.PRintln("Json unmarshall statement has been executed.")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

You could ignore the function, it's mainly for some learning purposes. The important part is that I am relying on a story package, which has been declared as part of the module.

When I go inside /tests and run 'go test' I receive:

```
cyow_test.go:5:2: package story is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/story)
```

I have ran 'go mod tidy' inside the module root directory and my simple questions are:

1. Why Go does not find out the package by default ? It's a package part of the module, so it schould come natively - this is my assumption.
2. Does that mean that the only way to refer to packages ( even inside your module ) is to reference them through a remote repo URL, like github.com ... or eventually just copy the package to /usr/local/go/src ( which is not friendly at all )

Comment: A directory contains a single package, `story.go` cannot be another package. If you create `story` in a new directory, then it is imported as `modulename/story`. I suggest you try the introductory tutorials, like [Create a Go module](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module) and [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. The way to import a package is 'module/package'. The module name does not have to include a repository name. Do not copy packages to go source directory.